# Is there a plugin allowing me to limit membership on WordPress to the members of a specific LinkedIn group?

Tags: wordpress

I want to create an alumni community with [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) for a school providing training to professionals, and I want to limit access to that website to the members of a specific [LinkedIn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinkedIn) group. Is there a plugin allowing that?